# Taking prescribed amphetamines to Dubai or India

Tags: customs-and-immigration, india, health, uae, drugs

Are you allowed to bring prescribed amphetamines to Dubai or India from the USA?

Comment: For UAE you are likely to need pre-approval http://www.mohap.gov.ae/Files/MOH_Service/361/Travellers%20Guideline.pdf

Comment: See also https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/international-travel/International-Travel-Country-Information-Pages/UnitedArabEmirates.html